# Прошивка TP-Link WR743ND на DD-WRT

Tags: маршрутизатор, прошивка, tp-link, dd-wrt

Вот появилась прошивка DD-WRT на мой роутер ревизии 1.х. Хочу прошить его.
На [официальном сайте](https://dd-wrt.com/) нашел 3 файла, но каким файлом перепрошить я не пойму. Если есть опыт в этом деле то помогите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, а что тут непонятного ? очевидно же что первым.

Comment: Для меня не понятно, я не перепрошивал их. Был бы один файл то ясно а тут 3 и каким не понятно. А для чего второй и третий файл?

Comment: Description в имени файла как бы намекает...

Comment: Ну первый я понял для установки, а второй и третий. Второй это что типа возврат к редакции оригенальной прошивки, а третий?

Comment: Для установки на пустой девайс (без какой либо прошивки)

Comment: Вот теперь все ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Прошивка ключенная оказалась. При применении некоторых настроек роутер виснет. Или вообще пропадает wi fi.

Comment: некоторые настройки должны вешать модем или отключать wifi, возможно ваш адаптер не поддерживает эти функции, либо вы задаете кривые параметры. вам на форумы dd-wrt а не сюда, возможно что нибудь подскажут или баг починят.

Answer (score 0):

Только еще одна фишка есть: если залита прошивка с русским интерфейсом, тогда обновите прошивку(можно скачать с сайта производителя) с английским интерфейсом.

Comment: Я бы сказал чуточку по-другому. Если что-то не работает, или работает плохо, то надо вернуться к ОРИГИНАЛЬНОЙ прошивке, и оттуда уже танцевать обратно! А оригинальная, как правило - английская, ну, в смысле, на английском языке.